# How to trigger pressure plates from a distance?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

What ways are there to trigger pressure plates without standing on them?

Say I sneak into an old ruin and come across a posse of skeletons that are so positioned to be completely decimated if I could just trigger the trap they are standing next to!

Comment: Get your companion to walk over them, they seem to be good at doing that when you don't want them to.

Comment: @DoozerBlake oh my god they are amazing at this.... I was in a dwemer ruin and there were moving spinning blade traps. I was smart enough to move around them but man my companion cannot figure out how to move through them. He kept getting hit and pushed back to the start.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I've triggered floor plates with projectile spells (such as frost bolt and fear) as well as arrow shots.  I've also dropped linen and bowls on them.

Comment: Projectile spells also trigger runes, by the way, although it seems that not all element type spells trigger all element type runes.

Comment: Ah, that's good to know.  I've been activating runes with my face.  Your way seems safer.

Comment: also, If you have the telekenesis spell, you can throw an object over there and hopefully it'll land on the plate

Comment: Doing the unrelenting force shout triggers the pressure plates aswell altough you might just push the minions away aswell

Comment: There is a slight delay before traps go off, so Whirlwind Sprint will get you out of the way before it hits you. This is true for runes as well!

Answer (score 3):

I used Lydia. If your difficulty is low enough, she's pretty difficult to kill too, and while the flames killed me instantly (though I'm not sure if that impacts her health), they didn't seem to bother her too much, as I made her burn twice, within 10 sec.