# Is it possible to disable or disarm floor traps in Skyrim?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

So I'm walking along in a dungeon, happy as can be, thinking of bunnies, when **BAM**, giant spikey gate to the face. Or I'm set on fire. Or impaled. All rather annoying.

Almost every dungeon has traps triggered by stepping on sort-of concealed floor plates. I was wondering if there is a way to disable them, especially since followers are rarely smart enough to step around them. Having to go into command mode, order them carefully around the trap, and then move forward myself is a huge waste of time.

Is there any way I can disable them, either temporarily or, better yet, permanently (while I'm in the dungeon at least)?

Comment: Related: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/39036/how-to-trigger-pressure-plates-from-a-distance

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you place something on top of a pressure plate trap, such as a corpse, it will keep it triggered so it will not reset.  Note, the trap will trigger the first time you do this.

However, this does not work for traps such as the fire traps that trigger when you stand on them as they'll keep burning until the weight is removed.

Another way to avoid this issue (PC ONLY) is to give the light foot perk to your follower via the console.

Comment: @desaiw I select them via the console and type addperk <id>.  Same way basically, except this way I don't have to look up the follower's ID

Answer (score 9):

I know your question pertains mainly to pressure plates, but I would like to make a note about trip rope traps.

Trip rope traps can be triggered remotely by shooting the rope with an arrow.

Comment: They can also manually be triggered.  Target the rope from a fairly close distance, and you'll be given an option to do this.

Answer (score 2):

Why not just be more careful...?

But more seriously, there is a perk in the sneaking tree that prevents pressure plates from activating when you stand on them. I think it was called light-footed.

Comment: he's specifically asking this question because of his follower triggering the traps, not himself...